# Changing Youtube Player Screen Size According to Browser's Window Size

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, screen-size, browser-scrollbars

If i use code below to get browser screen size there will be border and scroll bars. I want it to exactly get fitted to window no matter i open toolbars etc. I don't want border spaces and scroll bars. Neither horizontal nor vertical. Can you give me a clue to do it? By the way there is a [demo](http://olmasigereken.com/demo) and a screenshot below.

```
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried resetting you css especially the margin:0; padding:0 or use something like normalize, tried looking at your css but it could not find the files.

Comment: yeah if you look in chrome and the dev tools you get: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://olmasigereken.com/demo/styles/style_user.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://olmasigereken.com/demo/styles/style.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://olmasigereken.com/demo/styles/dialogs.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ..... this could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try resetting your css a little

```
 * html, body {margin: 0; padding:0;}
```

this worked for me